# How to display results from search below the form

Tags: php, html

i would like to ask if someone could help me with a search query and displaying of the results.

Here is the code...

```
<?php
// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="dasi";
$db_password="**************";
$db_name="dasi";
$db_tb_name="test";
$db_tb_atr_price="price_vat";
$db_tb_atr_cur="currency";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE code like '%".$query."%'");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $data_fetch['code'] . "</td><td>" . $data_fetch['price_vat'] . "</td><td>" .  $data_fetch['currency'] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
echo "</ol>";



mysql_close();
?>
```

In content i added the form ...

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<label>Search For: </label><input name="query" type="text" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Start Search" />
&nbsp;</form>
```

So ... all is working normaly.. i am getting the results, everything is fine. Problem is: 
i want to have results displayed below the form itself, not in a new page.

If anyone could help me that would be great. Thank you in advance

P.S.

Well i have no idea how it works actualy but was thinking, isnt there a way where the result can be added into empty div below the form or something like this? I tryed the options above but it dosnt helped.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works at all since you are sending the data with POST method and you $query getting the data from GET method?

Comment: ye noticed, i fixed that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your table in to a variable:

```
$table = "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    $table .= "<table border=1>";
    $table .= "<tr><td>" . $data_fetch['code'] . "</td><td>" . $data_fetch['price_vat'] . "</td><td>" .  $data_fetch['currency'] . "</td></tr>";
    $table .= "</table>";
}
$table .= "</ol>";
```

And print it in your template:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<label>Search For: </label><input name="query" type="text" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Start Search" />
&nbsp;</form>
<?php echo $table ?>
```

Comment: thats abit hard to be done. I am having a CMS that control dynamic pages...i am writing the code direcly in the content and i cant use <?php ?> there

Answer (score 0):

Just embed your **`form`** code in your **`search.php`** and then check for **`isset($submit)`** and you are good to go.

```
<?php
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Search For: </label><input name="query" type="text" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Start Search" />
    &nbsp;</form>
<?php

if(isset($submit))
{
// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="dasi";
$db_password="**************";
$db_name="dasi";
$db_tb_name="test";
$db_tb_atr_price="price_vat";
$db_tb_atr_cur="currency";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE code like '%".$query."%'");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $data_fetch['code'] . "</td><td>" . $data_fetch['price_vat'] . "</td><td>" .  $data_fetch['currency'] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
echo "</ol>";



mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: I tryed this, but result is.. just displaying the form in a new page

Comment: @ДобромирСтоянов Which would mean your form is probably on `index.php`, move the form onto `search.php` __or__ move the Search PHP into `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You've got two choices,

1. Use `AJAX` to actually get the results to 'collect' the PHP Generated Content and use JavaScript to append it to somewhere on the page.
2. Place the Search Algorithm and PHP Code at the top of the same page of the form, then use an [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) `$_GET` or `$_POST` to check if it's been submitted successfully, save the results & content to be later printed elsewhere.